# Print 108 square boxes in A4 paper?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

How do I fit 108 square boxes in A4 paper, there should be a little gap between consecutive squares. Is there any easy way to do it.. Im usually given "x" number of squares that needed to fit in A4 paper.. there isnt any required size for square..

[image]

Like the pic above, but 108 square boxes, and no "Lets Do This"

Comment: 12 rows x 9 columns of squares will probably fit the aspect ratio best. Do you have a full-bleed printer? If not, how close to the edge can you print? Or do you have other preferred margin values?

Comment: 20mm squares should fit, with ~3mm gaps, depending on stroke (line) width.

Comment: Make a 10x10 table + another 8 in MS Word, LibreOffice Writer, or whatever.  Should be easy.  Just turn on borders and cell padding/spacing.

Comment: @Spiff and ,, Print Margin Value 1cm from the edge, The problem is I dont know where the square is, Where Do I find it in MS-Word